# How to pass parameters to Broadcast receiver class?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, handler

I have created a Broadcast receiver and it is working fine. but I need to pass a handler to that class.

```
 public static class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        Handler handler;

        DataReceiver(Handler loghandler) {
            this.handler = loghandler;
        }

          @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //things goes here
        }
}
```

Currently I am using like this & It is working if constructor override is not available.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataReceiver .class);
```

but I need to pass the handler too. How can I send the handler? Thanks

Comment: `but I need to pass the handler too` Why?

Comment: To maintain existing data flow\

Comment: Then change it. Use localbroadcastmanager

Comment: Why does this `BroadcastReceiver` exist in the first place? And why are you using `Handler`? You cannot pass a `Handler` in an `Intent` extra, so your approach needs to be rewritten anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish but i think this may help you. You don't need to make a whole new class for your broadcast receiver but you can use it inside your Main Activity like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiveLocationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Your custom action
        }

    };

    IntentFilter receiveLocationFilter = new IntentFilter();
    receiveLocationFilter.addAction("android.intent.RECEIVE_LOCATION");
```

Register the receiver in "onStart":

```
registerReceiver(receiveLocationReceiver, receiveLocationFilter);
```

Unregister it in "onStop":

```
unregisterReceiver(receiveLocationReceiver);
```

Then when you need to send the broadcast all you need is :

```
Intent sendBroadcastIntent = new Intent("android.intent.RECEIVE_LOCATION");
sendBroadcast(sendBroadcastIntent);
```